# requireNativeComponent: "BingMapsView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, maps, bing-maps

Could not implement bing map in react native expo

<BingMapsView

```
credentialsKey="somekey"
        mapLocation={{ lat: 
12.9010875, long: 77.6095084, 
zoom: 15 }}
        style={styles.box}
      />
</View>
```

Comment: Provide more detail about what debugging steps and online/doc searches you tried first.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a problem with Android configuration. As you can see here https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android `requireNativeComponent` is used to define the native view on the JS side. Probably you need to clean your node modules and install them again and rebuild your project

Comment: It didnt work, it's still showing same error

Comment: what is your react native version?

Comment: its "react-native": "0.69.5",